# How to create a customised format for the bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, custom-bib

How can I get my bibliography section to follow this format:

*Books:*

Surname, First name, Title. Place of publication Year of publication.

> Kreis, Georg. Insel der unsicheren Geborgenheit: Die Schweiz in den Kriegsjahren 1914-1918. Zürich 2014.

*Incollection*

Surname(author), First name(author), Title. *In:* Surname(publisher), First name (publisher). Book title. Place of publication Year of Publication, page number.

> Joris, Elisabeth. Krieg, Propaganda und Geschlecht. In: Dejung, Cristoph und Stämpfli, Regula (Hg.). Armee, Staat und Geschlecht. In: Die Schweiz im internationalen Vergleich 1918-1945. Zürich 2003, S. 229-248.

*Web sites:*

Surname, First name. Title. In: *URL* (date of last access)

> Heather, Peter. The Fall of Rome. In: http://www.bbc.co.uk/history/ancient/romans/fallofrome_article_01.shtml (28. März 2014).

The fields are all available and filled in in my .bib file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Your terminology -- specifically, the use of the term `article` to characterize an entry whose type looks to be `@incollection` -- is somewhat confusing. The `@article` entry should be used only for pieces published in academic journals. Please clarify.

Comment: I've noticed that you've set the tag `custom-bib`. Indeed, the `makebst` utility, which is a part of the `custom-bib` package, is there to create highly customized bibliography style files. Is your query, then, about how to run the `makebst` utility? If so, which parts of the utility are causing trouble. Incidentally, you've left a *lot* of formatting aspects uspecified. E.g., if (and how) should the conjunction between multiple authors be shown: as a comma, an ampersand, or something else? And many further questions need to be resolved. Presumably, you have these pieces of information, right?

Comment: Yes, the "articles" are in rather `@incollections`.

Comment: I have tried using the `makebst` package, but I can’t seem to figure out how to use it, at all. Unfortunately, this is all the information/instructions I have received for the formatting.

Comment: Open a command window and type `pdflatex makebst`. You'll be guided through a long series of questions. Most take several possible answers, and one of them -- marked with `*` -- is the default. The 3rd question, `Name of the final OUTPUT .bst file?` is one of the few questions without a default answer; if yout type `test` and hit return, the file `test.bst` will (eventually) be created. The final question is "Shall I run the batch job now?" I suggest you type "y".